Fitting random slope for a subject-level predictor
In a nutshell, I am trying to understand whether it makes sense to include random slopes for group-level (or subject-level) predictors in a mixed effects model?
Some Background: I am fitting a mixed effects model explaining the percent cover of plants based on two predictors (Urbanness and PollinationType) and their interaction. Data was collected from ~200 sites where all plant species that were present in a given site had their percent cover estimated. Urbanness (numeric) represents the degree of urbanization surrounding each site and PollinationType (biotic vs. abiotic) represents the mode of pollination known to be used by each plant species. Since my response variable varies between 0 and 1, I am using glmmTMB with the beta distribution. I am also including two random effects: SiteID and SpeciesID. The main effect of interest for me is the interaction between Urbanness and PollinationType. Currently, I have tried fitting a model with random intercepts-only which looks like the following...
m1<-glmmTMB(PercentCover ~ Urbanness*PollinationType + (1|SiteID) + (1|SpeciesID), family=beta_family(link="logit"), data=dat)
In the example I've explained above, "Urbanness" is a group-level predictor for SiteID since each site only ever has one value for urbanness (sites cannot change locations). Similarly, "PollinationType" is a group-level predictor for SpeciesID since each plant species only ever has one value for its pollination type (species cannot change traits). My question is... does it make sense to try including random slopes for group-level predictors? For instance, in a model that looks like the following...
m2<-glmmTMB(PercentCover ~ Urbanness*PollinationType + (1+Urbanness|SiteID) + (1+PollinationType|SpeciesID), family=beta_family(link="logit"), data=dat)
Or is this model inappropriate since there would be no variation in urbanness within a site and no variation in pollination type within a species?
I found another post (Getting mixed answers on when to include random slopes into crossed effects linear mixed model) which kind of addressed a similar issue. In that post, the author included an image (shown below) which illustrates my problem. Here, IQ is a group-level predictor for subject since subjects cannot change their IQ (hence why all points with the same colour are vertically stacked). But each subject was allowed to read multiple "items" so there's several data points per subject.

Any advice or comments would be appreciated!


In a nutshell, I am trying to understand whether it makes sense to include random slopes for group-level (or subject-level) predictors in a mixed effects model?

Random slopes will make sense when you have a fixed effect in the model that varies within levels of a grouping (in your case you have two crossed factors, SiteID and SpeciesID). Actually it's not clear from the question whether these factors are crossed or nested but that doesn't affect the rest of this answer.
and you want each

does it make sense to try including random slopes for group-level predictors? For instance, in a model that looks like the following...
m2<-glmmTMB(PercentCover ~ Urbanness*PollinationType
+ (1+Urbanness|SiteID) + (1+PollinationType|SpeciesID),
family=beta_family(link="logit"), data=dat)

Or is this model inappropriate since there would be no variation in urbanness within a site and no variation in pollination type within a species?

That is correct, it only makes sense when the variable for which you want to fit random slopes varies within the levels of the grouping factors SiteID or SpeciesID.

Thanks for your comments @RobertLong! They were very helpful. Yes the two random effects here (species and site) are crossed. Each species had the potential to be found in each site, but in reality this didn't occur very often.
